# $Y$ is a subspace of a normed vector space $X$ and prove that $d(x,M)=\sup\{|f(x)|:f\in X^*,\lVert f\rVert \leq 1, f|_Y=0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, duality-theorems

> Let $Y$ be a subspace of the normed vector space $X$ and let $x\in X$. Define 
>   $$d(x,Y)=\inf\{\lVert x+y \rVert,y\in Y\}$$
>
> Prove that $d(x,Y)=\sup\{|f(x)|:f\in X^*,\lVert f\rVert \leq 1, f|_Y=0\}$

I have proven that $d(x,Y)\geq \sup\{|f(x)|:f\in X^*,\lVert f\rVert \leq 1, f|_Y=0\}$. How to prove that the equality can be achieved?

Comment: Do you mean $d(x,Y)$?

Comment: @user160738 yes, that's a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use Hahn-Banach. Suppose $x \notin \overline{Y}$ (otherwise the problem is trivial). Define a linear functional $g$ on $Y \oplus {\rm Span \ } (x)$ by $g(y + \lambda x) = \lambda$ for any $y \in Y$ and any $\lambda \in \mathbb C$. What is the norm of $g$? Then use Hahn-Banach to extend $g$ to the whole of $X$ while preserving the norm - what does this tell you?

Comment: I think there is a small problem here: If $x$ belongs to the closure of $Y$, then the functional $g$ is not continuous, as then there is a sequence $(y_n)$ in $Y$ with $y_n\to x$, so that $g(y_n)=0$ does not converge to $g(x)=1$.

Comment: Good point, thanks! I've edited.