# Confusion on application of Hahn Banach Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

> Suppose $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Consider $C(\partial K)$. Prove the following statement:
>
> "If every continuous linear functional on $C(\partial K)$ which vanishes on all functions in a particular subspace $Y$ of $C(\partial K)$, is identically zero, then every $\phi\in C(\partial K)$ can be uniformly approximated on $\partial K$ by functions in $Y$."

This is actually a part of a theorem I am reading(namely Keldysh's Theorem). The proof says this statement is true by Hahn Banach Theorem, but doesn't say anything more. But I am confused why it is followed by Hahn Banach Theorem. I am not sure if I am missing something really obvious.

So what I have to prove is given $\phi\in \partial K$ there is a sequence $\{f_n\}\subset Y$ such that $|\phi - f_n|\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Let $T$ be a continuous linear functional such that $T(f)=0$ for all $f\in Y$, then by hypothesis $T(\phi)=0$. So $|T(\phi-f)|=0$. Now can I say that $|\phi-f|=0$ since $T$ is arbitrary continuous linear functional? If so, where did we use Hahn Banach theorem? I am really confused. May be I am wrong in my argument. Highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from Theorem 5.19 in Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis", which in turn is a corollary of Hahn-Banach:

Let $M$ be a linear subspace of a normed linear space $X$, and let $x_0 \in X$. Then $x_0$ is in the closure $\bar M$ of $M$ if and only if there is no bounded linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in M$ but $f(x_0) \neq 0$.

See  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160614/y-is-a-subspace-of-a-normed-vector-space-x-and-prove-that-dx-m-sup-fx/2160641#2160641)  for a sketch proof of a more general result. (In the notation of the post that I linked, you need the special case where $d(x,Y)  = 0$.)